# How to speed up shortest path routing using pgRouting?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I need to develop the shortest path routing query in PostgreSQL. I have my own map data that is a shapefile. From that shapefile I have made PostgreSQL database. It is a large database with around 60k entries. I have made one edge table from the dataset and then created the topology. Lastly tried with astar and dijkstra algorithm (pgr_astar and pgr_dijkstra). It is giving the shortest path but the pgr_astar or pgr_dijkstra query takes at least 3 to 4 sec to provide the result. But I need it faster, may be in msec.

There are lots of applications with routing in market and in those cases routing results come within fraction of seconds. What are the tricks to make it faster?

I have checked a few tricks to speed up. There are highway hierarchies, busy node hierarchies. But I can't use these to my application as most of my roads are forest roads. And my start and/or destination point is a point somewhere in between forests; not a city centre of a big city (so, not a busy node).

I tried to generate clusters and then to pre-compute routes between clusters. But thus the database is growing significantly. So, I am not sure whether it will increase the speed or not.

Can you give any more easy idea to solve this problem?

Comment: A lot of the tricks are due to heuristics for pruning possible paths. In pgRouting, you pass a table name into say, pgr_dijkstra, from which a graph is created. So, if you were just searching in California, it would be pointless to pass in a table representing roads in New York, for example. So, one thing you can do is pass a subset of the 60k entries into the function, if you know you will only be searching in a certain area.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know my searching area

Comment: There are other tricks as well, such as pre-computing main routes between major nodes, eg, San Francisco and New York. If you are starting from somewhere in rural Nebraska, once you hit this trunk, you don't need to explore up into New Hampshire or down into Florida. When you say there are lots of applications, you are talking about the Googles, Heres and Tomtoms of this world, who will have lots of other tricks, such as pre-computed routes, parallellized searches, and giant datacentres with fast cores. So, while they might use A* or Djikstra at some level, there are other things going on.

Comment: So, you are not really comparing like to like, as a query passing the entire table as a graph to pg_dijkstra or pgr_astar every time vs the tricks the Googles of this world would use is not really fair. I think you probably need to add a few more details about your use cases, areas, road types, anything really to help narrow down the question, which while interesting, is very vague as it currently stands.

Comment: @JohnBarça My routing area is mainly around forests. I have checked a few tricks to speed up. There are highway hierarchies, busy node hierarchies. But I can't use these to my application as most of my roads are forest roads. I tried to generate clusters and then to pre-compute routes between clusters. But thus the database is growing significantly. So, I am not sure whether it will increase the speed or not. Hopefully now it is clear.

Comment: Can you put what you have tried in an edit to the question. It is a very interesting problem. I will certainly vote to re-open it, once you have done that.

Comment: Okay, now explained a little more.

Comment: Modern routing tools like [Graphhopper](https://www.graphhopper.com) and [Open Source Routing Machine](http://project-osrm.org) use [Contraction Hierachies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies), which is some kind of pre-computing. With CH calculating a route takes much less than 1 sec, using ordinary hardware. 
Unfortunately, pgRouting has not implemented this algorithm yet.

Comment: Yes @Mesa I also wanted to use contraction hierarchy and as pgRouting does not contain this, I switched to OSRM.

Comment: The trick with pgRouting is to limit the size of the network being queried to slightly larger than the area between the start and end points of the route. To do this: Draw a line between the 2 points, create a several km wide buffer and then use the streets inside the buffer in the calculation. This yields millisecond results for us using an Australia wide street network.

Comment: @minus34 The disadvantage of your approach is that the network is changed and therefore it is not guaranteed to find the optimal route -  the optimal route could be partly outside the buffer, depending on the road network.

Comment: pgRouting has the ability the pre-process data and do some sort of contraction. But it's not an out-of-the-box tool. It's a library, where you need to specify, how you want to contract your graph. Furthermore it's rather new functionality and therefor marked as "experimental": http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/contraction-family.html#contraction

Comment: @Mesa yes, that's the compromise. Testing is required to find a buffer big enough to create the best route whilst managing performance